# android instagram sign in without using webview

Tags: android, authentication, instagram-api

How to perform sign in with Instagram credentials in android without navigating user to Instagram website using Webiview? I have already tried https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE. But I need implementation for sign in similar to http://www.instaliker.net/

Comment: hi, you got any solution to your problem? I am also looking for something similar

Comment: You can't do this work .you can find the only ways of authentication  in this link : https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve user credentials and use Curl to send requests to the authentication site in the background and wait for the response.